# VSTS Extension Navigate To Hub from action

Tags: javascript, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to navigate to my custom hub from my extensions action context menu. When I do window.parent.location = url I get the error about changing the top level url from an iframe without the allow-top-navigation sandbox attribute.

What is the proper way to navigate to a hub from an action menu item (code item to my custom hub?). This is using the On-Premise version

```
var menuContributionHandler = (function () {
     "use strict";
     return {
         execute: function (actionContext) {

         var vsoContext = VSS.getWebContext();
         var extensionContext = VSS.getExtensionContext();

        window.top.location.href = vsoContext.host.uri
            + vsoContext.project.name 
            + "/_apps/hub/" 
            + extensionContext.publisherId
            + "."
            + extensionContext.extensionId;
            }
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get the same error when use "window.top.location.href" on on-Premise server while it can works on VSTS and finally I use "window.open" to open the hub in a new window as an alternative way. And you are missing the contribution id of the custom hub.

```
  var menuContributionHandler = (function () {
     "use strict";
     return {
         execute: function (actionContext) {
             var vsoContext = VSS.getWebContext();
             var extensionContext = VSS.getExtensionContext();
             var huburl = vsoContext.host.uri
                + vsoContext.project.name
                + "/_apps/hub/"
                + extensionContext.publisherId
                + "."
                + extensionContext.extensionId
                + "."
                + "customhubcontributionid";
             window.open(huburl);
         }
     };
 }());
```

Comment: Good clarification. I am using on-premise. I would prefer to keep it in the same window if possible.